# A *What* of air?

Tags: single-word-requests

> There isn't even a **drop** of water in the pond.

Suppose I want to frame a sentence like this with reference to something different, say wind.
How would I do this?

Specifically, I'm looking for a word that fits in this sentence.

> I didn't even feel a ___ of air today.

Maybe "molecule"?

Edit: Apparently, I wasn't clear enough. The context I want to use this sentence in is something like, not even a breeze about, and a completely still atmosphere. (It's the same way in which someone might shake a completely empty bottle and declare that there isn't even a drop of water in it.)

Comment: Wind is air in motion.  You can have a molecule of air, but probably not of wind.  Try *breath of wind* or *puff of wind*.

Comment: I think I actually meant *air*, not *wind*, I'll change it.

Comment: What do you want to express with the second example sentence?

Comment: Here is an example in Longman Dictionary: "*Scarcely a breath of air disturbed the stillness of the day."*

Comment: Breath, wisp, puff, gulp.  And there's "no hint of a breeze", etc.

Answer (score 1):

*I didn't even feel a **puff** of air today.*

> puff *n.* - a small quantity emitted in a blast.
>   Examples: puff of breath, 1667; of smoke, 1839; of vapour, 1869; of wind, 1400.
>   [Dictionary of Collective Nouns and Group Terms](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Puff)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=puff+of+air&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpuff%20of%20air%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

> The hot Texan day wore on like a tightly knotted cotton shirt. The stifling, humid, seemingly impenetrable atmosphere felt completely devoid of air. My heart felt as though it would cease, and nearly did once or twice as we awaited the verdict.

It appears to me that seemingly lacking in air is the concept you're after, but air could be metered in many ways, like counting breaths (and possibly molecules).

Edit: I just realized that I didn't really answer your question; a *good* word to use in your sentence could well be subjected to opinion, and dependent on context. A molecule of air seems to bring a very specific, tiny unit in contact with a broad, generalized group of various gaseous substances, and seems just a tad odd, although it appears to work. A morsel of air might be ludicrous, but then again, who knows?

Re-edit: molecule is definitely not what you're after if in pursuit of describing windlessness. Consider selecting a replacement for air, as, "A negligible amount of airflow was noted."

Answer (score 0):

As to quantity you typically would need "a bit of air". For new ideas, a "breath of air".
But in this context I'd use "a gust of air" or "breath of wind".

For more:
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/wind1_1

Answer (score 0):

If talking about wind, you could say:

> I didn’t even feel a gust of wind today.

If you say:

> I didn’t even get a breath of air today.

… that is not really about air. It is not literal, or you would be dead. It is an expression that means you didn’t get a moment to relax. Also stated like this:

> I didn’t even get a chance to breathe today.

Water doesn’t just come in drops, it also comes in trickles and streams and gushes and waves and more. Same with air. It comes in gusts and breaths and puffs and clouds and more. So there is more than one word that fits your blank.